# Visual Studio 2010 Themes, change Parameter Help background color

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Recently I installed in Visual Studio 2010 the [Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) It's working great, however I have problems with my text coloring theme ([Nightfall](http://studiostyles.info/schemes/nightfall)), and the extension's Colorized Parameter feature.

Since the theme text fore color is grey, when the Power Tools Extensions shows the Parameter Help tooltip using my text colors, it gets unreadable:

[image]

Is there a way to change Parameter Help background color?

Comment: Hi, there. It looks like you use the power tools, but still have the old tooltips. How did you manage to do that? I can't stand the advanced object type tooltip thing they implemented, but there seems to be no option to disable it.

Comment: The standard tooltips appear only on method autocompletion. The new browser replaces the old tooltip only when inspecting and object.

Comment: This happens to me all the time in VS2019 without PowerToolsExtension when working through Remote Desktop. Any clue how to fix it today?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok finally I´ve found the answer [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fefI):

> Akil Burgess 
>   Hi,
>
> You can customize the background color
>   of the parameter help tooltip using
>   the option at
>   "Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts
>   and Colors->Signature Help Tooltip
>   Background". Modifying the background
>   color should make this feature work
>   better with your dark theme.
>
> I hope this helps! AkilI hope this helps! Akil

I done it yesterday and now it looks great!
[image]

Comment: Hmm... I discovered this pretty soon after installing VS 2010 and the Power Tools, but now I can't figure out how to make the signature help that pops up when you are calling a JavaScript function to look decent. It is white on silver.

Answer (score 0):

For those who weren't able to get it to work with the accepted answer, I was able to fix this by adjusting the colors for the ToolTip item in Windows Color and Appearance.