# The tooltip is not displaying as it should

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've just downloaded Visual Studio Color Theme and a dark color scheme for Visual Studio. This is how my VS looks now:

[image]

But I don't like the tooltip. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053158/visual-studio-2010-themes-change-parameter-help-background-color) question on StackOverflow, an I would like to make the tooltip look like the one in the marked answer. (Also the font size is not chosen by me, I don't know why is it like that)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to change it. You can experiment different backgrounds from **Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Signature Help Tooltip Background**.

Also before you import theme, you can edit the font from the theme file.

Comment: If you provide the entry name from the XML, I'll mark your answer

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by entry name, but you can use this theme generator (http://frickinsweet.com/tools), you can also edit the font and colors etc.

Comment: I have problem with that particular font, not with others. I haven't specified anywhere a fonst like that (a big font). In my settings, the font is `Consolas 12`

Comment: You should be able to override both the font and the color from the menu when Signature Help Tooltip Background is selected and by using the item background and font size dropdowns.

Comment: I found the `Editor Tooltip` in the options dialog in the combobox at the top. But there, I cannot change the backgorund and foreground color...